# NSXMLDocument's initWithContentsOfURL is sometimes really slow on loading a URL's contents

Tags: cocoa, download, initialization

As the title says, some URLs take less than a second to load in the browser, but in my cocoa app, running the following line repeatedly results in initWithContentsOfURL sometimes taking up to 30 seconds to load the URL. What may be the source of this problem?

I'm calling it like this:

```
NSXMLDocument* aDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:&err];
```

Edits:

- It is an HTTP document
- I'm using NSXMLDocumentTidyXML arbitrarily, are different options better?
- I'm loading the same URL every time, but some times it takes WAY longer than usual
- I am releasing this document correctly
- I am calling this from a seperate thread
- Looking at Activity Monitor, the times when the line takes 30 seconds to finish, Activity Monitor shows a spike in the beginning, and then no network activity for the rest of the time

Comment: Is the URL a file URL? or a http URL? How big is the XML? Why did you choose `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML`? What happens if you change the option? People can give better answers given more info!

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Is it the same URL every time, or are you trying different URLs? Are you releasing this object, or are you leaking the document? Have you profiled your memory usage?

Comment: Speaking of profiling, have you profiled your processor usage and network I/O? Instruments has several instruments that will help you here.

Comment: Are you calling this method on the main thread? If so, the whole app will be blocked until the call returns. Unless this code is in a separate thread, you should be using an asynchronous method of loading the XML instead such as the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: I've made more clarification edits in the question.

Comment: Well, `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` does some extra tidying up of the XML document. What happens if you change it to `options:0` ?

And, could you try downloading the XML file locally, and then measure how long it takes? This way, you can see which part (URL loading, XML parsing) is taking time.

Comment: I changed it to options:0, but it didn't make a difference :(

Comment: I still say you should profile in Instruments.